# Separate distribution for Unity2d?

Tags: unity-2d

Will there be a separate distribution for Unity 2d?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Unity2D is there to

> [...] provide the Unity desktop shell on hardware platforms that cannot currently support Unity's OpenGL requirement

It will be enabled when insufficient hardware support is detected.

For more, see [Unity2D](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D) in the Ubuntu Wiki.

Comment: Does that meany, Unity 2d will replace Gnome in the future?

Comment: Well, firstly, Gnome and Unity aren't alternatives, they work together. Ubuntu will still use a lot of Gnome, even if you have Unity2D enabled. Secondly, the complete ("pure") Gnome Desktop will still be available by default. You just have to select it on the login screen ("Gnome classic desktop"). As for the future: Nobody knows :)

Comment: With "Gnome" I juse mean the "Classic Desktop"

Comment: Yes maybe in the future they wont use gnome at all. And still further down in the future they will ditch Debian. And then Maybe we will also have them Ditching Linux.

Comment: @tinhed: haha, good joke. And Mark will become the new CEO of Apple